# Python logging with empty logfile

Tags: python, logging, module

I'm having problems with python logging. The code (as in the Logging Cookbook)

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh = logging.FileHandler('/mydir/test.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.debug('debug message')

class myclass():
    def __init__(self, tQ, rQ):
        logger.debug('Init myclass')
        ...
```

This creates the requested file `test.log` but its empty.
This module is started by another python script (tornado server). I noticed that the file permissions are

```
-rw-r--r-- root root ... test.log
```

whereas all other scripts belong to `pi pi` (scripts are running on RPi). I have tested to modify the permissions

```
-rw-rw-rw- pi pi ... test.log
```

and

```
-rw-rw-rw- root pi ... test.log
```

without any information being written to the file (reboot doesn't make any difference). In summary, a log file is created once, but never filled with the requested information - why?

Comment: Can you try it with basicConfig? logging.basicConfig(filename='/mydir/test.log',level=logging.DEBUG); logging.debug("test'). Also try logging.shutdown() at the end.

Comment: Not that it helps you but this works fine when run on my local system. Sorry for that.

Comment: @RvdK. Not really an option since myclass is fairly large class that I owned from another programmer. Its filled with logger.debugg(...). The original file had only <code>logger = logging.getLogger()</code>. I don't understand how he could get any logging from that?!

Comment: I had this issue and my fix was that the logging level needs to be explicitly specified. Without the explicit specification, the log file was empty